# How to get array of strings from nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, nested

How to get array of strings from nested object

Based on type it is required to get array of 'link'(s)
Source object:

```
const obj = {
  id: '01',
  options: {},
  children: [
    {
      id: '02',
      type: 'green',
      options: {
        link: 'http://some-page-023'
      },
      children: [
        {
          id: '03',
          type: 'black',
          options: {},
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: '04',
          type: 'green',
          options: {
            link: 'http://some-page-044'
          },
          children: [
            {
              id: '05',
              type: 'white',
              options: {},
              children: [],
            }
          ],
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '06',
      type: 'black',
      options: {
        link: 'http://some-page-258'
      },
      children: [
        {
          id: '07',
          type: 'green',
          options: {
            link: 'http://some-page-055'
          },
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: '08',
          type: 'white',
          options: {},
          children: [
            {
              id: '09',
              type: 'green',
              options: {
                link: 'http://some-page-023'
              },
              children: [],
            }
          ],
        }
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```

What I am doing:

```
const a = []

const getLinks = (data, ltype) => {
   if (data.children) {
     for( let el in data.children) {
       if (data.children[el].type === ltype) {
         a.push(data.children[el].options.link)
       }
       getLinks(data.children[el], ltype)
     }
   }
   return a
 }

 const result = getLinks(obj, 'green')
 console.dir(result, { depth: null })
```

this works fine, result:
[
'http://some-page-023',
'http://some-page-044',
'http://some-page-055',
'http://some-page-023'
]

But I need the function to return the array of strings (array should be init and returned by function), so
I need something like:

```
const getLinks = (data, ltype) => {
  const a = []
  function recursiveFind(children, ltype) {
    if (data.children) {
      for (let el in data.children) {
        if (data.children[el].type === ltype) {
          a.push(data.children[el].options.link)
        } else {
          recursiveFind(data.children[el], ltype)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  recursiveFind(data, ltype)
  return a
}

const result = getLinks(obj, 'green')
console.dir(result, { depth: null })
```

Comment: why a function if you use a global variable for the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second snippet is actually fine, you just got the parameter wrong:

```
const getLinks = (data, ltype) => {
    const a = []
    
    function recursiveFind(data, ltype) {
        if (data.children) {
            for (let child of data.children) {
                if (child.type === ltype)
                    a.push(child.options.link)
                recursiveFind(child, ltype)
            }
        }
    }
    
    recursiveFind(data, ltype)
    return a
}
```

Also note `for..of`, it's better than `for..in`.

Alternatively, you can get rid of the temp array and use a generator:

```
function *getLinks (data, ltype) {
    if (data.children) {
        for (let c of data.children) {
            if (c.type === ltype)
                yield c.options.link
            yield *getLinks(c, ltype)
        }
    }
}

result = [...getLinks(obj, 'green')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check the object directly and take the link and get a flat array of the nested structure.

```js
const
    getLinks = (object, ltype) => {
        const links = [];
        if (object.type === ltype) links.push(object.options.link);
        links.push(...object.children.flatMap(o => getLinks(o, ltype)));
        return links;
    },
    obj = { id: '01', options: {}, children: [{ id: '02', type: 'green', options: { link: 'http://some-page-023' }, children: [{ id: '03', type: 'black', options: {}, children: [] }, { id: '04', type: 'green', options: { link: 'http://some-page-044' }, children: [{ id: '05', type: 'white', options: {}, children: [] }] }] }, { id: '06', type: 'black', options: { link: 'http://some-page-258' }, children: [{ id: '07', type: 'green', options: { link: 'http://some-page-055' }, children: [] }, { id: '08', type: 'white', options: {}, children: [{ id: '09', type: 'green', options: { link: 'http://some-page-023' }, children: [] }] }] }] },
    result = getLinks(obj, 'green');

console.dir(result);
```

A slightly different approach with a closure over the wanted type.

```js
const
    getLinks = (data, ltype) => {
        const
            gl = ({ type, options: { link }, children }) => [
                ...(type === ltype ? [link] : []),
                ...children.flatMap(gl)
            ];
        return gl(data);
    },
    obj = { id: '01', options: {}, children: [{ id: '02', type: 'green', options: { link: 'http://some-page-023' }, children: [{ id: '03', type: 'black', options: {}, children: [] }, { id: '04', type: 'green', options: { link: 'http://some-page-044' }, children: [{ id: '05', type: 'white', options: {}, children: [] }] }] }, { id: '06', type: 'black', options: { link: 'http://some-page-258' }, children: [{ id: '07', type: 'green', options: { link: 'http://some-page-055' }, children: [] }, { id: '08', type: 'white', options: {}, children: [{ id: '09', type: 'green', options: { link: 'http://some-page-023' }, children: [] }] }] }] },
    result = getLinks(obj, 'green');

console.dir(result);
```

Comment: these `...`'s just move lots of data around without any obvious point.

Comment: @NinaScholz if not using flatMap()?